# Creating a Drop down List that actually does something when clicking on a specific option

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a drop-down list with Tkinter that actually produces an answer you can see in the GUI when you click on one of the options in the list. So far I've been able to create a list with the following options

```
options = [
    "Option A"
    "Option B"
    "Option C"
    "Option D"
]
```

The GUI window shows up with the drop-downlist but I can't make them actually do anything. Like if I want Option A to result in a statement I can see in the GUI that says purple or Option B to say Blue. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you create the OptionMenu, you have to associate his event changes to a function that is called after any change

You also need to pass to OptionMenu a StringVar() type ("optionList" on this code), which you will check when an event happens to the OptionMenu.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

# Create the window
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry("100x100")

# Catch the Check Button Event
def OptionMenu_CheckButton(event):
    messagebox.showinfo("Option Menu", "You have selected the option: " + str(optionList.get()))


# Create options for the drop down list
optionList = StringVar()
optionList.set("1")  # presets the first option
options = ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C", "Option D"]

# Creates an OptionMenu, and associates his event changes with the function OptionMenu_CheckButton
OptionMenu(tk, optionList, *(options), command=OptionMenu_CheckButton).pack()
tk.mainloop()
```